# how to expand list in list that included in some not-iterable objects to flat?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to expand list in list that included in some not-iterable
objects to flat.
I tried to do this using list comprehension, but I get an error in not-iterable objects.
How to expand this list to flat?

```py
# [[1, 2], 3] -> [1, 2, 3]
list = [[1, 2], 3]
flat = [item for sublist in list for item in sublist] # TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
print(flat)
```

---

In my environment, numpy is installed in addition to the standard functions.
I tried `numpy.concatenate(list).flat`, but I get an error.

```py
# [[1, 2], 3] -> [1, 2, 3]
list = [[1, 2], 3]
flat = numpy.concatenate(list).flat # ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
print(flat)
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not **iterable** object. I made a spelling mistake.

Comment: Do you include all iterable types in this ?  For example, if the list contains "ABC", do you expect it to come out as "A", "B", "C" ?  If not, then you'll need a solution that is more specific on iterable types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the iterables are only lists and only one level deep, you can do it in the list comprehension.

```
L    = [[1, 2], 3]
flat = [v for item in L for v in (item if isinstance(item,list) else [item])]
```

If there are multiple levels and a variety of iterable types, you will probably need a recursive function:

```
def flatten(L):
    if not isinstance(L,(list,tuple,set)): # you probably don't want str here
        yield L
        return
    for F in L:
        yield from flatten(F)

L    = [[1, 2], 3, ({5,6,7},[8,9],10)]
flat = list(flatten(L))

print(flat)
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this to see if that what's you're looking for:

It can `flatten` any levels (deeply nested) by recursively calling itself. Just be aware this did not do performance test yet, so there may be room to improve it.

```
import collections

def flatten(L):
    if isinstance(L, collections.Iterable):
        return [a for i in L for a in flatten(i)] # recursively calling
    else:
        return [L]
```

Running it:

```
lst = [[1, 2], 3, [[4, 5], 6] ]
print(flatten(lst))     # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
lst2 =  [[1, 2], 3, [[4, 5, [6]]], 7, 8]
print(flatten(lst2))    #  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  # deeply nested
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be more elegant solutions, but the trivial one would be to just iterate with a couple of `for` loops, checking value type:

```
flat = []
for item in list:
    try:
        for subitem in item:
            flat.append(subitem)
    except TypeError: # Not iterable, append as is
        flat.append(item)
```

Note this assumes the nesting is only one level deep.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I highly recommend avoid identifiers such as **list**, **dict**, **set** etc. as these are data-types from Python and even though the syntax is allowed, you will "hide" them from the usage in your application.

Also, as a suggestion, avoid using list comprehension for more complex operations, as they can become difficult to read.

I recommend the following approach:

```
my_list = [[1, 2], 3]
flat = []
for item in my_list:
    if isinstance(item, list):
        for val in item:
            flat.append(val)
    else: flat.append(item)
print(flat)
```

Using list comprehension, the solution would look like:

```
my_list = [[1, 2], 3]

flat = [v for item in my_list for v in (item if isinstance(item,list) else [item])]
print(flat)
```